# How to read cookie expiration in dot net core?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I see you can set the expiration using CookieOptions when appending a new cookie to the response. However, HttpContext.Request.Cookies returns an IRequestCookieCollection, which only seems to give you key/value pairs.

Is there a way to read the CookieOptions (specifically the Expiration) for request cookies?

I'm using .Net Core (1.0.0-preview2-003131)

NOTE: I need to read the expiration of an arbitrary cookie in request processing, not the expiration of the framework generated auth cookie.

Answer (score 6):

I'm getting that by reacting to the event "OnValidatePrincipal"

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
... 
Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
OnValidatePrincipal = CookieAuthenticationEventHandler.ValidatePrincipalAsync
}
});
```

And then I can access, once the principal is validated, when the cookie will expire in my ValidatePrincipalAsync with the property `context.Properties.ExpiresUtc`

To be able to get that expires property later in my controller, I'm adding it in my HttpContext this way:

```
context.Request.HttpContext.Items.Add("ExpiresUTC", context.Properties.ExpiresUtc);
```

But I'm not really happy with that part, maybe someone can give you a better way to access it directly in the controller without having to get it from the OnValidatePrincipal.

Comment: Thanks - though I need to read this for an arbitrary cookie in request processing, not for the auth cookie.

Comment: I see, that I haven't done. Let's see if someone else can assist.

Comment: @Daboul, were you able to find how to read auth cookie? i need this too. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, HTTP does not include any details about cookies sent on requests, only their name and value. The auth cookie workaround only works because the expiration is also embedded in the value.

Comment: It's stored in the AuthenticationProperties collection as shown in the other answer above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42045462/2588374 You can get it from the cookie auth events or by calling HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync.

Comment: I thought you were able to get it inside the controller directly, since it's embedded in the value.

Comment: The cookie value is serialized and encrypted, you can't read it directly. The Cookie Auth handler decrypts and deserializes it for you into a ClaimsPrincipal and an AuthenticationProperties collection.

Comment: Can we manually decrypt it then? If possible in the controller, since we have the encrypted value in there.

Comment: Not easily. You'd be better off calling HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync in the controller to get the decrypted values.